# How to access json object/data in datatable server side processing in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, laravel-5

We're using with datatables on a new project and due to the large amount of data we are working with, we are using the server side processing of datatables.But right now we're trying to figure out how to get all the data from the server through datatables.As I use the Custom HTTP variables server side processing and as I take a look with the data returned, there are no values coming from the database. How could I access  the data? Please help. Thanks a lot. Here are my code

**javascript:**

```
$('#table-prod-contents').DataTable({
              processing: true,
              serverSide: true,
              ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
                  url: '{{ url("postproductsdata") }}',
                  pages: 6000, // number of pages to cache
                  "data": function ( d ) {
                     console.log(d);
                  }
              } ),
              columns: [
                  {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                  {data: 'category', name: 'category'},
                  {data: 'pharmaceutical', name: 'pharmaceutical'},
                  {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
                  {data: 'type', name: 'type'},
                  {data: 'unit', name: 'unit'},
                  {data: 'price', name: 'price'},
                  {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
              ],


          });
```

**The console,log only shows the data shown in the image below:**

[image]

[image]

**As I look inside the Object, there is no value of an id. Something like id: 31**

Controller.php

```
public function anyData()
{
    $conditionTxt = "Medical and Lab Supplies";

    $products = Product::where('category', 'ILIKE', '%'.$conditionTxt.'%')
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();

    return Datatables::of($products)->make(true);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `ajax.data` allows to define function to manipulate the data before it's **sent** to the server.

You could use `ajax.dataSrc` to get access to data **received** from the server, however you're also using [pipelining](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) which doesn't allow that.

Use either [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option along with [`ajax.json()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.json()) API method to get access to retrieved data or [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) option or [`xhr.dt`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event.

For example:

```js
$('#table-prod-contents').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
        url: '{{ url("postproductsdata") }}',
        pages: 6000, // number of pages to cache
        "data": function ( d ) {
           console.log(d);
        }
    } ),
    drawCallback: function(settings){
       var api = this.api();

       console.log(api.ajax.json());
    },
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'category', name: 'category'},
        {data: 'pharmaceutical', name: 'pharmaceutical'},
        {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
        {data: 'type', name: 'type'},
        {data: 'unit', name: 'unit'},
        {data: 'price', name: 'price'},
        {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
    ],
});
```